# Compilation error of pgfkeys package in circuitikz.sty

Tags: compiling, circuitikz, linux

Something really strange.

On my windows 10 environment my document is compiled, but in the ubuntu OS, i get the following message:

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/gas filled surge arrester
>   choice', to which you passed 'european', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps
>   you misspelled it.
>   See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
>   Type H  for immediate help.
>   ...

This circuitikz.sty is downloaded is the most newer version (updated two months ago).

My article is not simple enought to be uploaded, thus I uploaded only the error message.

Comment: Most likely, the ubuntu version has a (very) old TeX distribution

Comment: Sudo apt-get install texlive, should fix it? (I'm doing it right now)

Comment: Only if ubuntu has quite up-to-date TeX bundles (which wasn't the case in the past). I use another Linux distribution, but I download my TeXLive directly from the servers

Comment: I double checked it (with reinstall the TeX dist on my ubuntu, and install fresh ubuntu  and then install Tex dis) and still it doesn't work on none of them. Any other suggestion?